# how to read garmin gpx files in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, google-maps

Is there any way to read garmin's .gpx file in iPhone sdk? 
I want to display trails on google map.

Thanks
Saurabh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look [at this documentation](http://www.topografix.com/gpx/1/1/), it seems that a .gpx file is just a container for a xml file.

Using a `NSXMLParser`, you could load the file into a `NSXMLParser`, set the delegate to `self` (or whichever class you want to recieve the delegate methods), add the `NSXMLParserDelegate` into your classes interface file and receive the `parser:foundAttributeDeclarationWithName:forElement:type:defaultValue:` method, and you could filter the file's elements down to latitude and longlitude.

Answer (score 1):

If you want this in Google, why not try Google tours?

[Google tours](http://citytours.googlelabs.com/)